# Why OfficeJS changed code to asynchronous automatically?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Hi I am new to JavaScript and still don't know why my code run the "console.log("ok")" before the previous code. I have read lots of articles and watched some videos but still can't find the answer. Appreciate your help!

Edited:
It is very interesting. I added a new Promise to the code but the console.log still starts before the worksheet insert is finished. I may need to structure another function to get it work

```
function importProjects() {
  const myFiles = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file");
  var numberofFiles = myFiles.files.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < numberofFiles; i++) {

    new Promise(function(resolve){
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event) => {
        Excel.run((context) => {
          // Remove the metadata before the base64-encoded string.
          let startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
          let externalWorkbook = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);

          // Retrieve the current workbook.
          let workbook = context.workbook;

          // Set up the insert options.
          let options = {
            sheetNamesToInsert: [], // Insert all the worksheets from the source workbook.
            positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // Insert after the `relativeTo` sheet.
            relativeTo: "Sheet1" // The sheet relative to which the other worksheets will be inserted. Used with `positionType`.
          };

          // Insert the new worksheets into the current workbook.
          workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(externalWorkbook, options);
          return context.sync();
        });
      };
      // Read the file as a data URL so we can parse the base64-encoded string.
      reader.readAsDataURL(myFiles.files[i]);
      resolve()
    }).then(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("ok");
      },2000)
    })    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because FileReader's methods work async, the code below      `reader.readAsDataURL(myFiles.files[i]);` executes as the data is being read.

Answer (score 0):

`Excel.run` is asynchronous. (See the reference topic where it shows that it returns a Promise: [Excel.run](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-run-function(1)).) That means that the JavaScript engine starts it and immediately starts running the next line of code `reader.readAsDataURL(myFiles.files[i]);` That method is also asynchronous, so the engine starts it and immediately runs the `console.log`.

If you want the `console.log` to wait until after the previous code has finished, add the `await` keyword just to the left of the `Excel.run` and also just to the left of the `reader.readAsDataURL(myFiles.files[i]);`. You will probably also have to add the `async` keyword to the left of `function importProjects()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Excel.run is asynchronous." is the key. I have edited the code but the console.log still starts before the worksheet insert is finished.

Comment: Try replacing the "return" in front of context.sync with "await" or put `context.sync` (without the parenthesis at the end) inside a `then`.